# repeat calculate

Tags: functions, calculus-and-analysis, dynamic

I want　to calculate the below program x[t+1].But I can only calculate t=0,1. please tell me how to calculate t = 0 to 10.

```
d = 2;
k = 3;
f0 = 10;
x[1] := 0.1;
x[t_] + y[t_] == 1;
fx[t_] := fx[t] = x[t]*(k - d)/2 + y[t]*V + f0;
fy[t_] := fy[t] = y[t]*k/2 + f0;
x[t_] := x[t - 1]*fx[t - 1]/(x[t - 1]*fx[t - 1] + y[t - 1]*fy[t - 1]);
lst = Table[{t, x[t]}, {t, 0, 10}];
TableForm[lst]
ListPlot[lst, Joined -> True, PlotRange -> {0, Automatic}]
```

Comment: And I want to plot this function

Comment: What are you actually trying to do? Can you describe your application?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I hope you will become a regular contributor.  To get started,  1) take the introductory [Tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) now, 2) when you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge, 3) remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t), and 4) give help too, by answering questions in your areas of expertise.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is too localized and will most likely not be useful to future visitors.

Answer (score 4):

There are a couple of things wrong in your code: first you need to define the recursions consistently... here I've put all the t-terms on the left and t-1 on the right hand side. Next, you need to specify initial conditions (there weren't any for the fx and fy and the y was only defined implicitly (as 1-x). So here is syntactically correct code:

```
d = 2;
k = 3;
v = 1;
f0 = 10;
x[1] := 0.1;
y[1] = 0.9;
fx[1] = 0;
fy[1] = 0;
fx[t_] := fx[t] = x[t - 1]*(k - d)/2 + y[t - 1]*v + f0;
fy[t_] := fy[t] = y[t - 1]*k/2 + f0;
x[t_] := x[t] = x[t - 1]*fx[t]/(x[t - 1]*fx[t - 1] + y[t - 1]*fy[t]);
y[t_] := y[y] = 1 - x[t];
```

To run the recursion, you can use Table, I often use Map:

```
x[#] & /@ Range[2, 10]
```

To Plot

```
ListPlot[x[#] & /@ Range[2, 10]]
```